# ERROR: Could not find method viewBinding() for arguments

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to implement [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) on Android Studio as [described](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#setup) in the documentation.

But I get following error:

> ERROR: Could not find method viewBinding() for arguments
>   [build_86jkemkg0wj9ybuijdbbuahly$_run_closure1$_closure5@2714f9c5] on
>   object of type
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

I have the latest version of Android Studio for Linux.

Why I am getting an error?

Comment: To confirm, by "latest version", do you mean Android Studio 3.6 Canary 11 or higher?

Comment: Help->About says Android Studio 3.5. Also, lastest build at "https://developer.android.com/studio/" is 3.5. Is it a feature that will be implemented at next version?

Answer (score 27):

**8/3/2020 update**
After update to AS 3.6.1 you should update your android gradle version to `3.6.1` > `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'`
**Orignal solution**
Android Studio 3.6 and above, From the Left menu, select `Project` > `Gradle Scripts` > `gradle-wrapper.properties`
then modify the `distributionUrl` and set it to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip` after that sync your project with `Sync Project with Gradle Files`, after it's finished go back to your `build.gradle (Project)` and update the dependencie of gradle classpath to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'`, almost done.
 Now it's time to enable it, in your `build.gradle(:app)` set it

```
viewBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

**12/16/2020 update**

With `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'` `viewBinding` is deprecated, you have to use:

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding = true
}
```

Answer (score 18):

> Help->About says Android Studio 3.5

View binding is a part of Android Studio 3.6. Right now, that is in a preview ("canary") release version.

> Is it a feature that will be implemented at next version?

Correct. If you wish, you can install the preview version of Android Studio 3.6 alongside your Android Studio 3.5, to experiment with the feature. Or, you can wait a few months for Android Studio 3.6 to ship a release version, then use view binding at that point.

Comment: Thanks, CommonsWare. I think I have to import ButterKnife library for view injection.

Comment: Converting existing project to work with View binding in AS 3.6 also requires changes to:
* `gradle-wrapper.properties` change gradle version to `5.6.1`
* `build.gradle. change `com.android.tools.build:gradle` version to `3.6.0-beta04`