# Enable viewBinding feature failed (Android Studio 3.6)

Tags: android, android-studio, binding, android-databinding

I have installed Android Studio 3.6 Canary 12 and I want to use `viewBinding` feature

According to the documentation, I put this code in my build.gradle (app module)

```
android {
   ...
   viewBinding.enabled = true
   ...
}
```

But I get this error

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'viewBinding' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.
```

Need help ! Thanks !

Comment: Check your Android Gradle Plugin version in your top-level `build.gradle` file. Make sure you are using the version that matches your Android Studio version.

Comment: Thanks. It required Android Gradle Plugin 3.6.0-alpha12. After choosing it that's ok !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for you support !

I've solved it by using `Android Gradle Plugin 3.6.0-alpha12`

Comment: FWIW, I wrote up [a blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/09/22/view-binding-android-studio-versions.html) with a bit more about this.

Answer (score 5):

As given in [Official Website](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Put it like:

```
android {
    ...
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

## Please check your Android Studio Version too, It must be `3.6 Canary 11+`.

## Also check Gradle Plugin - `Android Gradle Plugin 3.6.0-alpha12`

> NOTE: View binding is available in [Android Studio 3.6 Canary 11+.](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview)

Comment: No difference ! That's the same declaration

Comment: Please check your Android Studio Version too, It must be 3.6 Canary 11+.

Comment: It required Android Gradle Plugin 3.6.0-alpha12. After choosing it that's ok ! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Some things have changed a little if you are using Android Gradle plugin >= 4.0.0-alpha05.

`viewBinding.enabled = true` is now deprecated

You should use the Android `buildFeatures` block instead:

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        // Determines whether to support View Binding.
        // Note that the viewBinding.enabled property is now deprecated.
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

If you want the feature enabled by default in all of your modules you can turn on it in `gradle.properties`:

```
android.defaults.buildfeatures.viewBinding=true
```

> Docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/#4.0

Answer (score 0):

Please check the solution from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60394118/4690298). and update your AS to the stable version of AS 3.6